# iw scan and wireless tools display different values

Tags: c, linux

This relates to my previous post:
[Wireless.h How do I print out the signal level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079771/wireless-h-how-do-i-print-out-the-signal-level)

After figuring out how to print that in a "dBm" form, I realised that it actually has some differences in comparison to the "iw" tool installed on the OpenWrt.

I used the wireless router at a close range from an Access Point using both the "iw wlan0 scan" command from the OpenWrt terminal, and I also ran my program.

The "iw" method returned a correct value of around -14dBm but the program only displays down to about -50dBm ... Which is not accurate AT ALL.

Any ideas what might cause this? Is it the conversion I used to print out the signal level? as seen in the referred thread above? Or some other reason I didn't think of?

```
printf("Transmit power: %d ", (int8_t) result->stats.qual.level);
```

This is how I print out the signal strength in my program which I saw from **wireless.h** part of Wireless Tools:

```
struct  iw_quality
{
    __u8        qual;       /* link quality (%retries, SNR,
                       %missed beacons or better...) */
    __u8        level;      /* signal level (dBm) */
    __u8        noise;      /* noise level (dBm) */
    __u8        updated;    /* Flags to know if updated */
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about showing us your code? The current version of it?

Comment: I said it is relevant to my previous post. If you go there you will see some of my code. Nothing complex: just this: printf("Transmit power: %lu ", result->stats.qual.level); which I changed to this printf("Transmit power: %d ", (int8_t) result->stats.qual.level);

Comment: Isn't that incorrect? Did you read the comment in the answer you accepted?

Comment: The answer I accepted in the other post has no comment. What do you mean exactly that it is incorrect?

Comment: It pretty much only consists of a comment (from that source code that the answer links to). About checking the IW_QUAL_DBM flag. And about weird ranges like "Absolute/dBm values are always encoded between -192 and 63.".

Comment: @thejh So how would I print out the signal level to look like the "iw" output? e.g. -14dbm when the signal is pretty strong.
I found this line in wireless.h file (version 29)   #define IW_QUAL_DBM  0x08 /* Level + Noise are dBm */