# Fetching wifi SNR via wireless.h for wlan interface on linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, wifi

I have created the following c programm in order to fetch SNR via the wireless.h hear on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/wireless.h>
#include <iostream>


unsigned char get_snr(char *iface)
{
    int sock = -1;
    struct iwreq pwrq;
    memset(&pwrq, 0, sizeof(pwrq)); 
    strncpy(pwrq.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ); 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }    
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &pwrq) != -1)
    {   
        unsigned char snr =(int8_t)pwrq.u.qual.qual; 
        close(sock);
        return snr;         
    }    
    close(sock);
    return 0;   
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  unsigned char snr = get_snr("wlan0");  
  printf("snr is  %u\n", snr);
  return 0;
}
```

For my case I get the value 73.
At header wireless.h header is mentioned that :

```
struct iw_quality {
    __u8        qual;       /* link quality (%retries, SNR,
                       %missed beacons or better...) */
    __u8        level;      /* signal level (dBm) */
    __u8        noise;      /* noise level (dBm) */
    __u8        updated;    /* Flags to know if updated */
};
```

So the qual refers to  link quality (%retries, SNR, %missed beacons or better...)
Since I haven't found any more detailed description I'd like to ask if the 73 value I get refers to SNR (73 db)  or to a more generic quality indicator and if so how can I extract only the SNR value?

Comment: `#include <iostream>` - what is that?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I inserted iostream in order to use (uint8_t) based on that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079771/wireless-h-how-do-i-print-out-the-signal-level, otherwise I get 0 value